# pip install osmnx errors

Tags: python-3.x, osmnx

[image]

I'm getting error while "pip install osmnx" Could anyone explain the problem, else, what to do? I'm using pycharm python 3.7.

[image]

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958055/7321942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pip install osmnx error in the pic attached has no image. Based on the search, is we need to go for [osmnx package](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and try installation statements given
conda create -n ox -c conda-forge python=3 osmnx
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
the first statement built two types of interpreters.as other packages work with (conda activate ox EX,osmnx, networkx...ext) whiles others work with (conda deactivate). working with osmnx you need to conda activate ox. otherwise, conda deactivate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the required os package: "libspatialindex-dev".

After that, try again to setup OSMnx with pip.